# How to automatically send notification on your android app once you publish something on your wordpress website?

Tags: wordpress, android-studio, push-notification

I have a wordpress website and now I have made an android application also. Now I want that whenever I publish a post on wordpress site, a notification should pop-up on the android app for all users who have installed my android app and when a user click that notification it should open the link of that post in the webview inside the application.

I have tried Firebase Cloud Messaging but I haven't encountered any way to automate this thing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the save_post hook ?https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post/

You could make a call to Firebase when you save it to automate this procces.

Comment: Can you be more specific on how to make a call to friebase to automate this.